# Why position fixed doesn't work as expected?

Tags: html, css, position, fixed

I am doing maintenance of a website which uses bootstrap.
The problem is, as I am using "position: fixed" to float an element, but the element which is fixed is scrolling when scrolled.

It should be positioned fixed and doesn't move on scrolling

Following is the link of website I am working:
http://grupoinvesta.com.br/teste.html

Comment: Please [avoid link only answers](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/link-only-answers/info). Answers that are "barely more than a link to an external site” [may be deleted](http://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers).

Comment: There is a lot of divs no following the screen there

Comment: A bunch of problems in your question. A `fixed` element doesn't 'float' ...ever. And a `fixed` element stays in the same position on screen when scrolling. So, position:fixed actually works as expected. But maybe not as you expected. Use maybe `absolute` for that. But without any code shared, we cannot help you.

Comment: @Mihai T check my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove **transform property** from body and it will work

`body { 
    transform: scale(1.0); 
}`

and remove bottom from .social and add something like top:100px; instead of bottom:600px;

`.social { 
    top: 100px;
}`

Comment: @Keven Cardoso Happy to help!